# Catalina Trusted Root CA certificates are revoked - Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keychain, catalina, ssl

I have a trusted self-signed root CA named `CA` and I use that to sign a certificate for my local website, before I install CA's certificate and trust that, chrome shows me an error about the site SSL certificate `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`:
[image: Chrome SSL error]

So I install the root CA certificate and mark that as trusted, now chrome gives me an error about `ERR_CERT_REVOKED` but shows the certificate as a **valid** certificate!

[image: Chrome valid certificate is revoked]
[image: Chrome valid certificate is revoked]

After I installed my CA certificate, firefox trusts my website's certificate with no problem.

I'm using macOS Catalina and Chrome 78.

Comment: Is the root CA a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Make sure that you have a latest Chrome. I had this issue like 3 months ago and Chrome version 78 fixed my issue. What is the version of Chrome you have now?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 78, and root CA is a self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured out that macOS Catalina has a limitation on a certificate validity dates (and some other things), a certificate can't have a [validity period more than 825 days](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176) and my certificate was valid for about 5 years.

So I regenerate my certificate and replace the old one with a certificate that 
 has a smaller validity period and everything is working fine now!

---

According to [apple's support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176), a TLS certificate should meet this requirement:

- The key size must be at least 2048 bits.
- Hash algorithm must be SHA-2 or newer.
- DNS names must be in a SubjectAltName, not in the CN field only.

and if certificates are issued after **July 1, 2019**:

- The ExtendedKeyUsage extension must be present, with the id-kp-ServerAuth OID.
- **The validity period should be less than 825 days**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to solve it :

Step 1: Go to **Keychain Access** > Login on Mac.

Step 2: Delete two specific certificates: “**UTN DATACorp SGC**” and “**AddTrust External CA Root**”.

Step 3: Quit both **Keychain Access** and your web browser.

Step 4: Now reopen the web browser and enter the website address.

This should likely fix the issue

In addition, **net err_cert_revoked** errors in Chrome occur because of a faulty extension you’ve installed. So, delete your extensions one by one and try accessing the website again. If your extensions are at fault, it will help you find out which extensions are responsible so you can remove them.

Hope this both options can help you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply,I removed all my extensions and `ERR_CERT_REVOKED` still there, also I can't find `UTN DATACorp SGC`, and I can't delete `AddTrust External CA Root` form my **system root certificates**